# Remove audio from video using Python

Tags: python, audio

I need to remove all audio from a video and save the video without the audio. The original can de discarded.

All answers I've found use ffmpeg, but this is not really an option for my use case.

Comment: You can also use the python library moviepy to strip audio and save the file within a specific folder. [Here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/video-editing-python-moviepy/) some examples. You can simply set the audio to 0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use moviepy:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

videoclip = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
new_clip = videoclip.without_audio()
new_clip.write_videofile("final_cut.mp4")
```